# Insert javascript code into the head tags of the woocommerce thank you page

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

I'm trying to add some google tracking script to my thank you page. I've written this code which successfully injects the tracker into the  of the thank you with dynamic values, but I need, instead, to add it within the  tags.

```
function mv_google_conversion( $order_id ) {
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $currency = $order->get_currency();
    $total = $order->get_total();
    ?>
    <script>
      gtag('event', 'conversion', {
          'send_to': 'AW-746876528/x5W1CLfA8JoBEPDckeQC',
          'value': <?php echo $total; ?>,
          'currency': '<?php echo $currency; ?>',
          'transaction_id': '<?php echo $order_id; ?>'
      });
    </script>
    <?php
  }
  add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'mv_google_conversion' );
```

How would I be able to use this code, with the dynamic values in header.php, or is there a hook that targets the  tags on the woocommerce thank you page.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You will use the following to inject code on the head tags on "Order received" (thankyou) page:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'my_google_conversion' );
function my_google_conversion(){
    // On Order received endpoint only
    if( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' ) ) :

    $order_id = absint( get_query_var('order-received') ); // Get order ID

    if( get_post_type( $order_id ) !== 'shop_order' ) return; // Exit

    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id ); // Get the WC_Order Object instance
    ?>
    <script>
      gtag('event', 'conversion', {
          'send_to': 'AW-746876528/x5W1CLfA8JoBEPDckeQC',
          'value': <?php echo $order->get_total(); ?>,
          'currency': '<?php echo $order->get_currency(); ?>',
          'transaction_id': '<?php echo $order_id; ?>'
      });
    </script>
    <?php   
    endif;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: How do we move this further down in the `<head>`? It's currently coming before the actual Google Ads global site tag.

Comment: @Garconis You forgot about the hook priority (by default it is 10), so you need to specify it with a higher number like **`90000`** so in the code: `add_action( 'wp_head', 'my_google_conversion', 90000 );`… **Or you can also use `wp_footer` hook instead** of `wp_head`.… It should now be after Google Ads global site tag. If it works you could upvote this answer.